# Handle Space in AWS API Gateway API URL - I am using Dynamodb Proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a AWS API Gateway - and using dynamodb to read Data from database, its running good enough if I sent a parameter without Space.

URL Pattern: API_LINK/benchmark_performance/{benchmark}

if {benchmark} is replaced with a String with a space - AWS replies with no/blank data, No Error Reported. if the parameter doesn't have space in it then it sends data correctly. I also tried using JS URI_encoder method and send it but same result

If I test the AWS API End point from AWS console (parameter has Space), then the result is shown properly but the same URL gives no data when called from Browser or angular 2 Application.

Question: What should I do at AWS API Gateway Integration Mapping, that it gives me proper output and handles the space in parameter issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the answer : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html

I used :
$util.urlDecode()   (Decodes an "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" string).

how to use => 
$util.urlDecode($.input.params('yourParameterName'))

in Integration Mapping (section) of API Gateway